# M1 Macbook pro: "Add" button missing in automation > Security & Privacy Settings > System preferences

Tags: macbook-pro, applescript, security, automation

I've been wanting to add "Script Editor" to automation but there seems to be no button to add it. Is there any possible way of achieving this??

[image: Showing that there is no "add" button in automation.]

Comment: Apps are added under Accessibility.